# Upload And Remove image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a upload button on my web page, if i upload an image it should show preview below and i upload another image it should show next to the image and for third it should show next to the second image and so on, and once i click the click the "X" the image should be removed.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Image preview</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> 
</script>
<script>
var blank="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif";
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
      var img = input.value;
        $('#img_prev').attr('src',img).height(200);
    }
    $("#x").show().css("margin-right","10px");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#img_prev").attr("src",blank);
    $("#x").hide();  
  });
 });
 </script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("input:file").change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var file = $('#file_select')[0].files[0];
        console.log(file.size);
        //console.log(file.width);
        var reader = new FileReader();
         var img = new Image();
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(_file) {
            img.src= _file.target.result;
            //$('#img_preview').append('<img src="'+ img.src +'"/>');
            $('#previewPane').append('<img id="img_prev" src="'+ img.src +'"   
alt="your image" /><span id="x">[X]</span>');
            //console.log(img.src);
            console.log(img.width);
         } 
       }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
#x { display:none; position:relative; z-index:200; float:right}
#previewPane { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<input type='file' name="file" id="file_select" onchange="readURL(this);" />   
<br/>
<span id="previewPane">
</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using multiple jQuery versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `readURL` and `onchange="readURL(this);"` on `input` which is doing samething(I beleive) with `$("input:file").change`.
2. Create a `div.imageContainer` to Wrap both `img` and `span`, so when X on the `span` is clicked, it knows which image to be removed.
3. Add a delegated click event listener to `$('#previewPane')` and told it to react to every `click` that is sourced from `.remover`, which is an added class on the span, so we don't need to register each click event when a new image is coming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Image preview</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> 
</script>
<script>
    var blank="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif";
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var file = $('#file_select')[0].files[0];
        console.log(file.size);
        //console.log(file.width);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var img = new Image();
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(_file) {
            // Create a container for image and span X
            $imageItem = $('<div>').addClass('imageItem');
            $(img).appendTo($imageItem);
            $('<span>').html('x').addClass('remover').appendTo($imageItem);
            img.src= _file.target.result;

            // Append the container to panel
            $('#previewPane').append($imageItem);
            //console.log(img.src);
            console.log(img.width);
        } 
    }

    // Deletegate for dynamically created span, so we don't have to register a
    // new event listener each time a new imageContainer is created.
    $('#previewPane').on('click', '.remover', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.parent('.imageItem').remove();
    });
});
});//]]>

</script>
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    #x { display:none; position:relative; z-index:200; float:right}
    #previewPane { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<input type='file' name="file" id="file_select"/>   
<br/>
<span id="previewPane">
</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple :

```js
 

   
 $(function(){
    $('input[type=file]').change(previewFile);
   
    
 function previewFile() {
     var el=$('#preview');
  var preview = $(document.createElement('img'))[0];
     preview.height=200;
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
     var imgdiv=$(document.createElement('div')).append(preview).append('<span>x</span>');
      $(imgdiv).find('span').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });
     el.append(imgdiv);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" ><br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL